# Handlebars-require plugin not compiling the template

Tags: jquery, requirejs, handlebars.js

I am using the the `require` handlebars plugin (https://github.com/SlexAxton/require-handlebars-plugin), I integrated to my app as well...

here is my template:(as a sample)

```
<div class="best plugin ever">
  This is my {{ adjective }} template.
</div>
```

in the view.js i am calling the template and compiling:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'hbs!scripts/login/template/login1Temp.hbs'],
    function ($,_,Bacbone,loginTemplate) {
        "use strict";
        socialApp = window.socialApp || {};

        socialApp.loginView = Bacbone.View.extend({
            el:'div#header',
            initialize:function(){
                var html = loginTemplate({adjective: "favorite"}) //i am using handlebars temp. 
                this.$el.html("<p>This is weekend! </p>"); //it works
                this.$el.html(html); //it not working, i am getting my static html duplicates!
            }
        });

        return socialApp.loginView;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine, after I remove  the file extension from the `define`. the poor doc make this struggle.

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'hbs!scripts/login/template/login1Temp'], //removed the extension.
    function ($,_,Bacbone,loginTemplate) {
        "use strict";
        socialApp = window.socialApp || {};

        socialApp.loginView = Bacbone.View.extend({
            el:'div#header',
            initialize:function(){
                var html = loginTemplate({adjective: "favorite"}) //i am using handlebars temp. 
                this.$el.html("<p>This is weekend! </p>"); //it works
                this.$el.html(html); //it not working, i am getting my static html duplicates!
            }
        });

        return socialApp.loginView;
    }
);
```